# Why I'm creating an empty object at the end of my array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm sending info to my database depending of the day and everything is working well but when I make the push to the array sending the new object, I'm creating an empty object and I don't want to create it.

This is my function that creates a new object:

```
const nuevoPick = async (req, res, e) => {
  const tipsterId = req.body.tipster;
  const title = req.body.title;
  const description = req.body.description;
  const fecha = req.body.fecha;
  const category = req.body.category;
  const pickImageUrl = req.body.pickImageUrl;

  try {
    const tipster = await Tipster.findById(tipsterId);

    if (!tipster) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        msg: "Tipster no existe por ese ID",
      });
    }

    let lastPickStored = tipster.picks.slice(-1)[0];

    const yesterday = moment().subtract(1, "days").format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY");

    const date = moment().format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY");

    const ultimoPick = lastPickStored.data.slice(-1)[0].date;

    const newPick = {
      title,
      description,
      date,
      category,
      pickImageUrl,
    };

    if (ultimoPick === date) {
      console.log("El último pick fue publicado hoy");

      const tipsterUpdate = {
        picks: [
          ...tipster.picks,
          {
            ...lastPickStored.data.push(newPick),
          },
        ],
      };

      console.log(tipsterUpdate);

      const tipsterActualizado = await Tipster.findByIdAndUpdate(
        tipsterId,
        tipsterUpdate,
        {
          new: true,
        }
      );

      res.json({
        tipster: tipsterActualizado,
      });

      // Send Push Notification

      const notification = await {
        headings: {
          en: " Nuevo Pick de " + tipster.name,
          es: " Nuevo Pick de " + tipster.name,
        },
        contents: {
          en: newPick.title,
          es: newPick.title,
        },
        included_segments: ["Subscribed Users"],
        android_channel_id: "4d196ac9-11b9-4f5b-beef-2b07e4f6c770",
      };

      const newPickNotification = await client.createNotification(notification);
    } else {
      console.log("El último pick fue publicao ayer");

      const newPick = {
        date,
        data: [
          {
            title,
            description,
            date,
            category,
            pickImageUrl,
          },
        ],
      };

      const tipsterUpdate = {
        ...req.body,
        picks: [...tipster.picks, newPick],
      };

      const tipsterActualizado = await Tipster.findByIdAndUpdate(
        tipsterId,
        tipsterUpdate,
        {
          new: true,
        }
      );

      res.json({
        tipster: tipsterActualizado,
      });

      // Send Push Notification

      const notification = await {
        headings: {
          en: " Nuevo Pick de " + tipster.name,
          es: " Nuevo Pick de " + tipster.name,
        },
        contents: {
          en: newPick.title,
          es: newPick.title,
        },
        included_segments: ["Subscribed Users"],
        android_channel_id: "4d196ac9-11b9-4f5b-beef-2b07e4f6c770",
      };

      const newPickNotification = await client.createNotification(notification);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json({
      ok: false,
      msg: "Hable con el administrador",
    });
    if (e instanceof OneSignal.HTTPError) {
      // When status code of HTTP response is not 2xx, HTTPError is thrown.
      console.log(e.statusCode);
      console.log(e.body);
    }
  }
};
```

But my response is this:

```
{
  '0': {
    date: 'Monday, February 21st 2022',
    data: [
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object]
    ]
  },
  picks: [
    { date: 'Saturday, February 19th 2022', data: [Array] },
    { date: 'Sunday, February 20th 2022', data: [Array] },
    { date: 'Monday, February 21st 2022', data: [Array] },
    {}
  ]
}
```

With that last empty object on the picks array that I don't want to create, can someone help me to find why I'm creating that empty array?

Thank you, I appreciate it.

Comment: can you add live snippet ?

Comment: `({ ...lastPickStored.data.push(newPick) })`, in your case, is the same as `({ ...4 })` which results in `({})`. Read the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).